# The mapping of a cost vector to the set of solutions of the respective LP is concave

Tags: optimization

I would like to know if I understood the following exercise (a part of a larger one) right:

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an nonempty compact set. Prove that the function
>
> $V: c \in \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \{ { min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \ \  c^Tx \ \ \ with \ x \in X} \}$
>
> is concave.

I did the following approach:

The definition of concavity of a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ for $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ is:

> > $f(tc + (1-t)\widetilde{c}) \ge tf(c) + (1-t)f(\widetilde{c})$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ and for all $c, \widetilde{c} \in A$.

But since our given funtion $V$ maps to a set and not to an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I supposed that I need to show the above inequality for every  arbitrary combination of solutions to our minimizing problem. So I wrote:

$V(tc + (1-t)\widetilde{c}) =  min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ tc^Tx + (1-t)\widetilde{c}^Tx \ \ \  with \ x \in X$

and by a simple comparsion we see that

> $ a \in min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ tc^Tx  + (1-t)\widetilde{c}^Tx  \ \ge \ b \in min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ tc^Tx  $
>
> $ a \in min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ tc^Tx  + (1-t)\widetilde{c}^Tx  \ \ge \ b \in min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ (1-t)\widetilde{c}^Tx   $

So we may conclude that

$V(tc + (1-t)\widetilde{c}) =  min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ tc^Tx + (1-t)\widetilde{c}^Tx \ \ \  with \ x \in X$

$\ge min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}   \ \ tc^Tx \ \ \  with \ x \in X \ \ \ \ + \ \ \ \  min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}  \ \ tc^Tx + (1-t)\widetilde{c}^Tx \ \ \  with \ x \in X$

$= tV(c) + (1-t)V(\widetilde{c})$

And since $c, \widetilde{c}$ were arbitrary this proves the concavity of V.
Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that your function maps to a set, but it maps to a set with just one element. I do not see why the set notation is necessary. Convexity of set-valued function is by no means standard ([although some theory seems to exist](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0893965996000201)). Let me just assume that the function is scalar valued.

The part of your answer "by a simple comparsion we see that" is not clear to me. Some terms could be negative.

$V$ is the minimum of linear functions, and is therefore concave. The proof is analog to [convexity of the maximum function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435464/show-that-max-function-on-rn-is-convex).