# Show strict convexity of expectation of the max of a linear function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, expectation, random

Let $V\equiv (V_1,..., V_M)$ be a random vector with all components continuous random variables. Consider the function $G\colon \mathbb{R}^M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with

$$
G(a)=\mathbb{E}(\max_{k\in \mathcal{M}} (V_k+a_k) )\equiv \int (\max_{k\in \mathcal{M}}( v_k+a_k))f(v)dv
$$
for any $a\equiv (a_1,..., a_M)\in \mathbb{R}^M$ and $\mathcal{M}\equiv \{1,...,M\}$, where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation, $v\equiv  (v_1,..., v_M)$ is a realisation of $V$, $f$ is the pdf of $V$.

Could you help me to show that $G$ is strictly convex and lower semicontinuous?

Comment: Could this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435464/show-that-max-function-on-rn-is-convex or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373229/show-that-the-maximum-of-a-set-of-convex-functions-is-again-convex ? Any further hint?

Comment: I think the inequality $\max\{a + b, c + d\} \leq \max\{a , c\} + \max\{b, d\}$  for real numbers $a, b, c$ and $d$ is enough to establish the result.

Comment: Could you elaborate more with an answer if you have time? Thank you

Comment: Because I have the integral which is confusing me. Thank you